# Alternative to array.splice in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, safari, splice

I am currently working on a project where I store numeric values in a JS array. After some changes it should be removed again. I currently use the array.splice method like this:

```
function removeA(arr, element) {
    var index = arr.indexOf(element);
    if (index >= 0) {
        arr.splice(index, 1 );
    }
    return arr;
}
```

But this seems to give me issues on Safari. This piece of code works in every browser, like Chrome, Firefox, Opera. But not on Safari. It even works in the Technical Preview of Safari.

Does anyone have an alternative?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: It doesn't remove the element correctly

Comment: what does it do instead?

Comment: It's basic JS, so if this doesn't work, you've got a problem with your `index`.

Comment: @OriDrori But wouldn't that make it work nowhere?

Comment: You probably do have a problem in Safari, but it's not `splice`. As you can see `filter` didn't work as well. And you may try my proposed solution, but it probably won't work either. Try `console.log(index)`, and the array, and see who's different before the operation.

Answer (score 13):

The best option is to use [`Array.prototype.toSpliced()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced), which is part of ES2023, and currently not supported by Firefox. It has the same api of `Array.prototype.splice()`, but it returns a new array, and doesn't mutate the original.

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var index = 5;

var result = arr.toSpliced(index, 1);

console.log(result);
```

You have to slice before and after the index, and `concat` the results. Note that `Array.prototype.slice()` doesn't mutate the original array like `Array.prototype.splice()` does.

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var index = 5;

var result = arr.slice(0, index).concat(arr.slice(index + 1));

console.log(result);
```

Or using ES6 and array spread:

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var index = 5;

var result = [...arr.slice(0, index), ...arr.slice(index + 1)];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the built-in **filter()**

```js
var array = [1,2,3,7,4,5,6,7,12,54,7,691];
var array = array.filter(x => x !== 7);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Looks like my reply wasn't saved. Your solutions also works on every browser except safari. The item just doesn't get removed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Another Alternative to `array.splice` in JavaScript is **`array.reduce`**

```js
var arr =[1,2,3,2,4,5,6,2];
var newarr = arr.reduce((acc, elem) => elem !== 2 ? acc.concat(elem) : acc, []);
console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `slice()` method

```
arr = arr.slice(index, 1 );
```

Comment: If the element is to be removed at the specified index, leaving all other elements in the array, would `slice` not give you the opposite result, leaving the array only with the element specified at the index, "removing" everything else?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late but hopefully it is useful for someone else

```js
var arr = [32, 33, 16, 40, 55, 2, 41, 3, 10];

document.write("Array : "+arr);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Removed Elements : "+mySplice(arr,2,2));
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Processed Array : "+arr);


function mySplice(array,index,count) {
  var fixIndex = -1;
  var ret = [];
  arr = array.filter(function(element) {
    fixIndex++;
    if((fixIndex >= index && fixIndex < (index+count))) {
        ret[ret.length]=element;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  });
  return ret;
}
```

Or you can use simple version (NOTE: it is simple but reversed)

```js
var arr = [32, 33, 16, 40, 55, 2, 41, 3, 10];
document.write("Array : "+arr);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Processed Array : "+mySplice_simple(arr,2,2));


function mySplice_simple(arr,index,count) {
  fixIndex = -1;
  return arr.filter(function(i) {
    fixIndex++;
    return !(fixIndex >= index && fixIndex < (index+count));
  });
}
```

Or if you have to remove just one element then use this

```js
var arr = [32, 33, 16, 40, 55, 2, 41, 3, 10];
document.write("Array : "+arr);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Processed Array : "+mySplice_simple_v2(arr,2));


function mySplice_simple_v2(arr,index,count) {
  fixIndex = -1;
  return arr.filter(function(i) {
    fixIndex++;
    return fixIndex != index;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more ideas:

##### Option A [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#map_and_flatmap):

Return an empty `[]` in order to "filter" elements. Less efficient but might be useful in case you want to add new elements as well.

```js
const a = [3, 4, 5, 6];
const filter = 2;
const r = a.flatMap((v, j) => j !== filter ? v : []);
console.log(`Result: %o`, r);   // Result: [3, 4, 6]
```

Example for filter + insert

```js
const a = [3, 4, 5, 6];
const filter = 2;
const insert = 1;
const value = 4.5;
const r = a.flatMap((v, j) => {
  if (j === filter) return [];
  if (j === insert) return [v, value];
  return v;
});
console.log(`Result: %o`, r);   // Result: [3, 4, 4.5, 6]
```

---

##### Option B [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const a = [3, 4, 5, 6];
const filter = 2;
const r = Array.from({length: a.length -1}, (_, i) => a[i >= filter ? i + 1: i]);
console.log(`Result: %o`, r);   // Result: [3, 4, 6]
```

---

##### Option C "Destructure":

```js
const a = [3, 4, 5, 6];
const filter = 2;
const {[filter]: _, ...o} = a;
const r = Object.values(o);
console.log(`Result: %o`, r);   // Result: [3, 4, 6]
```